# How can I connect to a remote machine and list all files in a directory?

Tags: perl, directory, rsh

I am on a Unix machine, and I need to remotely connect, via rsh, to a Windows machine and list all the files in a particular directory.

Most of the code I've read is really confusing. Are there any short examples how to do this?

Comment: rsh??? Without knowing what you hopre you achief, why don't you use smbclient to list your files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
rsh $machine -l $user "dir $directory"
```

should work fine.

try it like this:

```
my @files = qx(rsh $machine -l $user "dir $directory");
```

qx is a system call that returns its results as an array, one entry per line.

Just out of curiosity, can you link to a confusing example?